# Log file auto growth SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

My Logfile keeps auto grow even though approximately only half of the VLF is used, can anyone explain this?

See picture below. I truncated the logfile yesterday, this is the first load since and from my understanding the ones which have 0 as vlf sequence number haven't been used. But still the logfile auto grew, the one which have 150 in vlf_size_mb is auto grow. How come this happened?

[image]

picture below with not the same lsn, lsn last column.

[image: I didn't try anything]

Here is from the sys.trace_event as you can see the log did auto grow, does anyone know how this can happen without the VLFs beeing used?

[image]

Comment: What does `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases` say for this database?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] from my understanding the ones which have 0 as vlf sequence number haven't been used.

You're correct.

> But still the logfile auto grew [...]

The log won't grow, I highly doubt it automatically grew given the image in the OP which shows that the log reused some VLFs already and has not used the maximum size of the file.

One way to investigate is to look for autogrowths in the default trace which has event 93 for log autogrowth.

```
select trace_event_id, name FROM sys.trace_events where name like 'Log%grow%'
```

There is also the ability to run `sys.dm_db_log_info` to get the create lsn for the log, if it's all the same lsn then it did not grow.

Given the updated screenshots showing that auto grow did occur, the most likely explanation is due to log reservation as part of a large transaction.

All of the autogrowths happened when VLF 34627 was active and it looks as though it's still active. Given the parity change at VLF 34620 it's most likely that there was a large transaction running which required more space to be reserved and caused the log growth.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the answer! Do I understand you correct that SQL server estimated there would be a bigger transaction than it was and therefor reserved the extra space?

Comment: When any transactions occur, part of the job of the transaction is to reserve log space so that the operations can undo themselves if needed. The combination of reserved + used space could have made the log grow. It still seems odd to me that it'd grow so much, but we don't really have any other data and without re-creating the logs it's not very possible to get an exact answer, hence my best guess here with the data available.